# Why does my Knex migration fail on Heroku but not locally?

Tags: heroku, knex.js

I am trying to deploy my first React app on Heroku and everything seems to work fine until I get to the migrations. My Knex migration works fine locally but when I try to run it on Heroku the migration fails.

Since it works fine when run on my local machine and this is my first time trying to deploy anything, I'm not sure how to debug this.

Here is my migration code:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return Promise.all([
    // USERS TABLE
    knex.schema.createTable('users', t => {
      t.uuid('id')
        .primary()
        .unique()
        .notNullable();
      t.string('name').notNullable();
      t.string('email')
        .unique()
        .notNullable();
      t.string('password').notNullable();
      t.timestamp('joined', { useTz: false }).notNullable();
      t.text('website');
      t.string('github');
      t.string('twitter');
      t.text('avatar');
      t.boolean('is_admin')
        .defaultTo(false)
        .notNullable();
    }),

    // INSTRUCTORS TABLE
    knex.schema.createTable('instructors', t => {
      t.uuid('id')
        .primary()
        .unique()
        .notNullable();
      t.string('name')
        .unique()
        .notNullable();
      t.timestamp('created', { useTz: false }).notNullable();
      t.text('website');
      t.string('github');
      t.string('twitter');
      t.text('avatar');
    }),

    // TUTORIALS TABLE
    knex.schema.createTable('tutorials', t => {
      t.string('id')
        .primary()
        .unique()
        .notNullable();
      t.uuid('user_id').notNullable();
      t.uuid('instructor_id');
      t.string('instructor_name');
      t.string('title').notNullable();
      t.text('url')
        .unique()
        .notNullable();
      t.timestamp('date', { useTz: false }).notNullable();
      t.enum('cost', ['free', 'paid']).notNullable();
      t.enum('medium', ['article', 'video']).notNullable();
      t.enum('difficulty', ['beginner', 'advanced']).notNullable();
      t.specificType('categories', 'text ARRAY').notNullable();
    }),

    // COMMENTS TABLE
    knex.schema.createTable('comments', t => {
      t.string('id')
        .primary()
        .unique()
        .notNullable();
      t.uuid('user_id').notNullable();
      t.string('tutorial_id').notNullable();
      t.text('body').notNullable();
      t.timestamp('date', { useTz: false }).notNullable();
    }),

    knex.schema.createTable('tutorial_votes', t => {
      t.uuid('id')
        .primary()
        .unique()
        .notNullable();
      t.string('tutorial_id').notNullable();
      t.uuid('user_id').notNullable();
      t.smallint('vote_value');
    }),
    knex.schema.createTable('comment_votes', t => {
      t.uuid('id')
        .primary()
        .unique()
        .notNullable();
      t.string('comment_id').notNullable();
      t.uuid('user_id').notNullable();
      t.smallint('vote_value');
    }),
    knex.schema.createTable('favorites', t => {
      t.uuid('id')
        .primary()
        .unique()
        .notNullable();
      t.string('tutorial_id').notNullable();
      t.uuid('user_id').notNullable();
      t.timestamp('date', { useTz: false }).notNullable();
    })
  ]);

  console.log('Tables created successfully');
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return Promise.all([
    knex.schema.dropTable('users'),
    knex.schema.dropTable('instructors'),
    knex.schema.dropTable('tutorials'),
    knex.schema.dropTable('comments'),
    knex.schema.dropTable('tutorial_votes'),
    knex.schema.dropTable('comment_votes'),
    knex.schema.dropTable('favorites')
  ]);

  console.log('Tables dropped');
};
```

And here is the error I get:

```
remote:        migration file "20190731184441_setup.js" failed
remote:        migration failed with error: Cannot read property 'all' of undefined
remote: TypeError: Cannot read property 'all' of undefined
remote:     at Object.exports.up (/tmp/build_7917ecdef592ca80a65bfdee9b4e67c6/server/db/migrations/20190731184441_setup.js:2:18)
remote:     at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_7917ecdef592ca80a65bfdee9b4e67c6/server/node_modules/knex/lib/migrate/Migrator.js:503:40)
remote:     at Object.tryCatcher (/tmp/build_7917ecdef592ca80a65bfdee9b4e67c6/server/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
remote:     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/tmp/build_7917ecdef592ca80a65bfdee9b4e67c6/server/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
remote:     at Promise._settlePromise (/tmp/build_7917ecdef592ca80a65bfdee9b4e67c6/server/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
remote:     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/tmp/build_7917ecdef592ca80a65bfdee9b4e67c6/server/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:641:10)
remote:     at _drainQueueStep (/tmp/build_7917ecdef592ca80a65bfdee9b4e67c6/server/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:97:12)
remote:     at _drainQueue (/tmp/build_7917ecdef592ca80a65bfdee9b4e67c6/server/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
remote:     at Async._drainQueues (/tmp/build_7917ecdef592ca80a65bfdee9b4e67c6/server/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
remote:     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/tmp/build_7917ecdef592ca80a65bfdee9b4e67c6/server/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
remote:     at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
```

Comment: My guess is that in heroku, the `Promise` param of the migration function is not supplied, so `Promise.all` throws the exception you are seeing. Not sure what the solution is, suggesting this as a debug-oriented observation. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is likely to be a version mismatch between what you have locally and what Heroku has installed. If your semver specification was quite permissive, that would allow Heroku to install a more recent version, and perhaps you've been developing against the local one for quite awhile.

The reason I suspect this: Knex [switched to native promises](https://github.com/knex/knex/blob/master/UPGRADING.md) in version 0.18.0, which means that migrations are no longer passed a Bluebird `Promise`. That parameter doesn't exist anymore, hence your error.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by removing `Promise` from `exports.up = function(knex, Promise)` & `exports.down = function(knex, Promise)`